# gevent monkey patch stops rabbit mq listting messages

Tags: python, rabbitmq, monkeypatching, pika

I am using gevent threads in my python flask application, rabbit mq messaging seems to be working fine when i am not monkey patching python thread but rabbit mq client pika stops listening when i do gevent monkey patch. would like to knows about this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue is Pika and gevent.monkey_patch are not compatible when using rabbitmq.You will have to use gevent without patching system calls, if that is possible.
In case of if you are using threads with gevent then you might get this issue `greenlet.error: cannot switch to a different thread`
This is because of monkey patching.For this you can try use process instead of threads.